# What kind of algorithm can be used to have a random selection of question, just like in a quiz game?

Tags: unity, random

We were trying to create a mobile game using Unity 5, and we don't have any idea for what kind of algorithm we're going to use.

Our game is like a logic quiz game, and we want the questions to be randomly picked for the users, in order to enhance their thinking.

What kind of algorithm can be used to have a random selection of question, just like in a quiz game, using Unity 5?

Comment: Use a shuffle bag: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/shuffle-bags-making-random-feel-more-random--gamedev-1249

Comment: I wish questions wouldn't be down-voted with no context!

Comment: just this `int number = Random.Range(min,max)` _ [useful link about random algorithm](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/117103/generate-random-numbers-in-loop-without-repeating)

Comment: If you read the description on downvote button `"This question does not show any research; it is unclear or not useful"`, I think it is pretty fitting - the author clearly did zero research, moreover they do not specify how exactly they want to choose them(repetition, topics, distribution, etc.).

Comment: See ["Randomize a List<T>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

It's quite a big question.

**Short answer.**
Assign every question a random number, sort the question list, take the top 5.

**Long answer.**
Do as above, remove questions from the list that have been asked in the last N days to stop repeats

**Longer answer.**
Ascertain if the question was good or not (Wheel of fortune asks for a thumbs up / down) and feed this into the ranking selection so popular questions are more likely to be asked.

Comment: This looks like the *start* of a good answer; but it is fairly minimal. Could you go into more detail? Perhaps make each "answer" its own heading, and provide some *light* pseudo code or more detailed explanation.